# Filtering join relationship with sqlalchemy

Tags: mysql, orm, sqlalchemy

I'm writing a query with sqlalchemy, and I feel I'm doing something not as it is meant to be done: The query I'm getting is too much complicated and so I think this is not the way one should use databases/orm.

This is a simplified version of my schema:

```
class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True, index=True)
    longs = db.relationship('Login', backref='users')

class Login(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'logins'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('users.id'))
    browser = db.Column(db.String(64)
```

I would like to have, for a given *status*, all the elements in A such that *the number of rows in B referencing A is less than a certain number*, let's say 5.

For a real case, imagine this:
A is the list of user
B is the list of login:

**I would like to have the list of all the user that logged-in less than 5 times with Firefox).** This includes also user that never logged in!

In SQL/sqlalchemy I would do this in this way:

1) select rows, using a left join, that don't have a login at all

```
never_loggedin = session.query(User).join(Login,
Logins.user_id == User.id).\
        filter(Login.user_id == None)
```

2) select logins with Firefox and take only those with a count less than 5.

```
sub_query = session.query(Login).filter(Login.browser ==
browser).subquery() 
less_ex = session.query(User).outerjoin(sub_query,
sub_query.c.user_id ==
User.id).group_by(sub_query.c.user_id).having(func.count(User.id) <
repetition)
```

3) Now I have the issue. There might be user that logged in but NEVER with Firefox, and those are not selected from previous query. I don't know how to select those.

I'm I proceeding correctly? Specifically, I suppose I should have used a many-to-many relationship, but I think I'm gonna put this edit in the next re factoring of the software.

Comment: hum.. maybe just a select and a "not in" select might be the solution...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  sub_query = session.query(Login.user_id).filter(Login.browser == browser).group_by(Login.user_id).having(func.count(Login.id) >= repetition).subquery()
  less = session.query(User).filter(~User.id.in_(sub_query))
```